# After Changing Bot Framework Folder Structure, the Messaging Endpoint returns a Bad Request error

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I created my Bot Service using the Azure portal and choose the basic template to use, which had the run.csx file in the "messages" folder. I have updated the folder structure to match my needs better and removed the "messages" folder, replacing it with a folder called "Default" instead.

I tried to update my messaging endpoint to point towards "/api/Default?code=", where  was the value previously there when the messaging endpoint pointed towards "/api/messages", but now I am getting a Bad Request error:

> BadRequest
> {
>
> "Message": "The 'code' query parameter provided in the HTTP request did not match the expected value."
>
> }

I'm not sure how to get this "code" value and what it should be. Logs don't say what it should be and I can't find documentation on this.

Comment: Have you removed run.csx file and message folder which might be pointing to end point is removed? You can try adding more files to the same folder and editing the ones which are by default.

Comment: Is your bot a Node.js, or c# bot?

Comment: Sorry to not provide the information before.

I did remove the messages folder. Still using the original run.csx, but I placed it into the Default folder instead. Use of the messages folder no longer made sense in my bot.

It's a C# bot.

Comment: This is my exact scenario, but the answer below doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentioned in another forum:

Here are two ways to retrieve the bot service key code:

1) go through the kudo console and find the function's secrets .json file: https://[YourBotId].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/data/Functions/secrets/messages.json

2) open the function app's blade instead of the bot service blade and then find the function's (messages in bot's case) key/code/secrets